# What is uncontrolled logging policy?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I am reading [Learning from Logged Implicit Exploration Data](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.0120)

It says

> Formally, given a dataset of the form S = (x, a, r_a)* generated by the **interaction of an uncontrolled logging policy**

What is such a policy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This policy is usually referred to as the Behaviour Policy when talking about off-policy learning. It is the policy that actually takes actions in the world. The policy that one wants to learn, such as a greedy policy in Q learning, is know as the target policy. In this way the behaviour policy “logs” experience that the target policy (or policies) may learn from.